# BackboneJS - Add different view or layout when .fetch() returns error?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-layout-manager

Can I add a different View or Layout in case of fetching an collection returns error?

Right now, I'm doing it like this:

```
this.artistsCollection.fetch({
    error: function() {
        $('div.artistsDiv').append('<div class="tc"><span class="font-entypo icon-three-dots emptystate-big"></span></div>');
    }
});
```

But I was thinking of something like:

```
error: function() {
    App.useLayout('artistLetter', 'artistLetter').setViews({
        '.navMenu': this.navigation,
        '.alphabet': this.alphabet,
        '.artistsDiv': this.artists
    }).render();
}
```

OR

```
error: function() {
    $('div.artistsDiv').setViews({...
    })
}
```

So, is there a better way to do this? Otherwise I'm gonna continue with this method, since it works even though I want to do it the right way..

Comment: i think you should validate your code first.